# Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'open'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, database

I've been trying to make a simple site with Node.js, Express.js, and MongoDB. I'm new to these technologies and have been having problem set up the database
Here is snippet of code in my index.js file:

```
var http = require('http'),
    express = require('express'),
    path = require('path'),
    MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
    Server = require('mongodb').Server,
    CollectionDriver = require('./collectionDriver').CollectionDriver;

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

var mongoHost = 'localHost';
var mongoPort = 27017;
var collectionDriver;

var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server(mongoHost, mongoPort));
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
  if (!mongoClient) {
      console.error("Error! Exiting... Must start MongoDB first");
      process.exit(1);
  }
  var db = mongoClient.db("MyDatabase");
  collectionDriver = new CollectionDriver(db);
});
```

After I try to run `node index.js` in terminal, it says the following:

```
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version

/Users/username/dev/ga-final/index.js:31
mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) { //C
            ^
TypeError: Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'open'
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/username/dev/ga-final/index.js:31:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

What is wrong? Why can't I call open? Can you help me fix this? thanks!

Comment: ping check my answer :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is happening may be because you are using new version of mongodb it is working fine after I use mongodb driver version 1.4.

```
npm install mongodb@1.4.x
```

Comment: Glad to hep you @SarasArya :)

Comment: @practicemakesperfect If this worked for you please consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: So what is the work around for this for newer versions?

Comment: If I do not make mistake it we should use `mongoClient.connect (urlString)`, right?

Answer (score 8):

Take a look at the [`mongodb` docs](https://www.npmjs.org/package/mongodb). Your `mongoClient` object is not what you think it is, and that why there isn't an `open()` method available.

Make your example code look more like theirs:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
// Use connect method to connect to the Server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected correctly to server");

  db.close();
});
```

Comment: What about backward compatibility?

Comment: I think that was the problem. Original post was using older version of the library that supported `.open()` while the newer version used `.connect` instead. The lib authors did not keep it backwards compatible.