# Mongodb refuses to recognize mongoclient.open and mongoclient.db

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb, node.js and express and was making a small sample code and got hit through this error.

```
app.get('/',function(req, res){
    mongoclient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/views', function(err, db)
    {
        var db=mongoclient.db('courses');
        db.collection('hello_mongo_express').findOne({}, function(err, doc)
        {
            res.render('hello', {'name': 'MongoDB'});   
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the error

```
 oroborus@Saras-Dell-System-XPS-L502X:~/views$ node app.js
    Connected correctly to server

/home/oroborus/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:406
          throw err
                ^
TypeError: Object #<MongoClient> has no method 'db'
    at /home/oroborus/views/app.js:19:22
    at /home/oroborus/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:403:11
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I referred these link but none of these seem to help. 
[SO ques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626186/object-mongoclient-has-no-method-open)
[Mongo DB documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/1.4/api-generated/db.html)

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I solved the above. It was a problem of express version. Version 3 has this functionality but version 4 doesn't. It will be great if someone could re write the code compatible for express 4

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with mongodb node package version 2.0.27, using 1.3.10 version instead fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure you are you using the current version of the driver and try mongoclient.connect, rather than going back to a legacy version of the driver.

"mongoclient.open" is from version 1.4.9 found [here].[1](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/mongoclient.html#open) The current version is http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/